# How to interpret and fix brew doctor errors?

Tags: homebrew

I am having problems updating to a particular Ruby version. The failed install is prompting me to run brew doctor, to which I get the following output.

Is this something that I need to correct? And if so how?

```
Pauls-MacBook-Pro:~ pauldriver$ brew doctor
Warning: Passing arbitrary symbols to `option` is deprecated: :static
Symbols are reserved for future use, please pass a string instead
Warning: Passing arbitrary symbols to `option` is deprecated: :static
Symbols are reserved for future use, please pass a string instead
Warning: Passing arbitrary symbols to `option` is deprecated: :static
Symbols are reserved for future use, please pass a string instead
Warning: Passing arbitrary symbols to `option` is deprecated: :"build-examples"
Symbols are reserved for future use, please pass a string instead
Warning: Passing arbitrary symbols to `option` is deprecated: :"build-examples"
Symbols are reserved for future use, please pass a string instead
Warning: Passing arbitrary symbols to `option` is deprecated: :"build-examples"
Symbols are reserved for future use, please pass a string instead
Warning: Passing arbitrary symbols to `option` is deprecated: :"build-tests"
Symbols are reserved for future use, please pass a string instead
Warning: Passing arbitrary symbols to `option` is deprecated: :"build-tests"
Symbols are reserved for future use, please pass a string instead
Warning: Passing arbitrary symbols to `option` is deprecated: :"build-tests"
Symbols are reserved for future use, please pass a string instead
Your system is ready to brew.
```

Answer (score 1):

They are warnings and the final line is the conclusion: Your system is ready to brew.
I wouldn't worry too much.

It looks like your Ruby version is newer than the one used to develop the version of Homebrew you have. Updating Homebrew (`brew update`) could fix the issues and remove the warnings.